# How can I add or subtract on Moment JS value in React Native State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

So my question is how do I get my state (date) to add or subtract value from it.

I am talking about a React Native App and I am using Moment.js in it.

```
state = {
    date: this.props.navigation.getParam("date")
  };
```

this is my date state and it shows correctly its passed threw React-Navigation and its working fine.

```
  dateBackHandler=()=>{
    Moment(this.state.date).subtract(1, "d")
  }

  dateForwardHandler=()=>{
    Moment(this.state.date).add(1, "d")
  }
```

these are my 2 functions that manipulate the state and that should add or subtract a day from it.

My problem is that I get the error:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions.

I clicked on the link and read the Moment.js docs.

I need a way to call my functions on my current state.

EDIT: Does anybody know how my setState should look like inside the function?

EDIT: By passing the date with no format my fucntions actually work and they change the day but it looks ugly because of the format it gets displayed.

Comment: What is the format of `props.navigation.getParam("date");`?

Comment: I am getting it as a String

Comment: I mean the format of the data ex: `dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss`

Comment: ah I got it formatted DD-MM-YY so today: 17-04-19

Comment: then try `moment(this.state.date, 'DD-MM-YY').add(5, 'd')`

Comment: Doenst work for me if I console log my state onClick it stays the same, do you know how my setState should look inside the func?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error, it's a warning. The problem is that the `this.state.date` is in a format that moment doesn't recognize. Send it something in ISO formar (I.E. `2019-04-15T00:00:00Z`). Things like `19-04-15` or `15/04/2019` are not valid values for moment)

Comment: Ok that might be it because I get it as 17-04-19, do you know how to convert it back?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is regarding to format of date you passing to moment i.e the `this.state.date` is in a format that moment doesn't recognize so when passing this.state.date to moment also pass format of date along with it as comma separated.
For example: `moment('17-04-19',"DD-MM-YY")`.

Test following `console.log` in your code:

```
 console.log(moment('17-04-19',"DD-MM-YY").subtract(1, "d").format('DD-MM-YY')); 
 // this will print --> 16-04-19
```

So, your function may need to change to get valid date format from your state.date format as follows:

```
 dateBackHandler=()=> {
   Moment(this.state.date, "DD-MM-YY").subtract(1, "d") // assuming your state.date is in format "DD-MM-YY"
 }

 dateForwardHandler=()=>{
   Moment(this.state.date, "DD-MM-YY").add(1, "d") // assuming your state.date is in format "DD-MM-YY"
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the formatting of the date to a compatible format, and then change it back to what you need:

```
moment(moment(this.state.date).add(5,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD')).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```